# Is it possible to join a child thread in a new created thread in c++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, join, boost

Case is the following: I have a main process, lets suppose with pid=1. The main process creates child threads which have the same pid and different thread ids. I want to join child thread without blocking the main thread, so I created a new thread from the main process and tried to join the child thread there without success. I was wondering, is it possible to join a child thread in a new created thread or it has to be the main process?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "child thread". Threads don't have parent/child relationships.

Comment: Well, except for the `main` thread, each thread is created in another thread. That defines a directed acyclic graph, a tree to be precise (since a thread cannot be created by two thread). Thus creation defines a parent/child relation.

Comment: They are more like clones than descendants.  main() is run by a thread created by the OS loader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least on linux (using pthreads) it should be possible. Quote from documentation:

```
All of the threads in a process are peers: any thread can join with any other thread in the process.
```

I would think you could do the same also on windows.

Comment: Tested it in Linux and works, I will have to try it on Windows as well.

Comment: Documentation: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html